# AjaxからWCFを呼び出した時、Account/Loginへのリダイレクトが発生しているようでうまく接続できません。

Tags: ajax, asp.net, wcf

【環境】
開発環境はWindows10で、VisualStudio2017CommunityのWebFormsです。
Windwos2012ServerにWCFサービスを配置しています。
【問題点】
接続を試みたところ、接続に失敗しました。Chromeの開発ツールで確認したところ、次のようなエラーが出ていました。本来の呼出先である、"SyouBu.svc/TopCate"から"Account/Login"にRedirectされているのが原因のようです。Account/Loginは今回は全く関係がなく、ソース等で思い当たる点はありません。
どのような修正方法が考えられるでしょうか。
なお、IPやドメインが異なる、環境が似ている別のWindows2012ServerにWCFサービスを配置したところ期待通りに動作したので、なおさらわからなくなっているところです。
[image: エラーメッセージ]

【コード類】
呼出元のAjaxは、以下の通りです。
なお、URLが直接指定なのは、Cordovaを用いてモバイルアプリにすることを考えているためです。

```
        function SetselCate() {
            ////alert('Bu')
            var iData = {};
            iData.Cate = cate;

            $.ajax({
                    　　
                url: 'http://**********.jp/SHOP/SyouBu.svc/SetselCate',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                data: iData,
                success: function (response) {
                    var cateset = JSON.parse(response.d);

                    $.each(cateset, function () {
                        var setCateID = this.cateid;                 
                    });
                },

                error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                    console.log(xhr);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(err);
                    alert('通信失敗');

                }
            });
        };
```

WCF部分は、以下の通りです。

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="")> <AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
    Public Class SyouBu

 <WebGet()>
Public Function SetselCate(ByVal Cate As String) As String

    Dim syoubu As New List(Of Object)()

            syoubu.Add(New With {
                    Key .cateid = "返り値",

    Return (New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(syoubu))

End Function

 <WebGet()>
Public Function TopCate(ByVal Cate As String) As String

    Dim syoubu2 As New List(Of Object)()

            syoubu2.Add(New With {
                    Key .cateid = "返り値",

    Return (New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(syoubu2))

End Function
End Class
```

また、Global.asax.vbは次のようにしており、クロスドメイン問題を回避していようとしています。

```
Imports System.Web.Optimization
Public Class Global_asax
Inherits HttpApplication

Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the application is started
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
End Sub

Protected Sub Application_BeginRequest(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore()

    EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall()
End Sub

Private Sub EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    If HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod = "OPTIONS" Then
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.[End]()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: 本文/エラーメッセージのURL(`TopCate`)とVB/C#のコード(`SetselCate`)のWebサービスメソッドが異なるようですが、任意のメソッドで同様の現象が発生するということでしょうか。

Comment: 実際の構成としてはサーバーA(もしくはリバプロ)に://serverA/SHOP/Account/Loginが配置されており、別のサーバー二台に://serverB/SHOP/SyouBu.svc/TopCateと://serverC/SHOP/SyouBu.svc/TopCateを配置しており、serverBのみserverAとの認証セッションの引継ぎが出来ていないという認識でよいでしょうか？でしたらIISのセッションストアの設定が異なっているような気がします。

Comment: 失礼しました。コードの記載が不適切でした。Webサービスメソッドが異‌​なることについては、「任意のメソッドで同様の現象が発生する」で良いです。

Comment: 実際の構成としては、同一のサーバーに/SHOP/SyouBu.svc/TopCat‌​eや/SHOP/SyouBu.svc/SetselCate、それに/SHOP/Account/Loginが配置されている状態です。/SHOP/Accout/Loginは、システム的には用いないものの、プロジェクト作成時についていたものをそのまま残しているものです。

Comment: WCF部分の記載コードを修正しました。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/59567

Comment: プロジェクトを作成するときから、テンプレートにAccout‌​/Login が無ければ、当該問題点はとりあえず回避できるのではないかと考え、プロジェクト作成のときからWCFのみでやってみた結果生じた問題がhttps://teratail.com/questions/59567 になります。このような場合もマルチポストということになるのでしょうか…。

Comment: いずれにせよ、不要なファイルをプロジェクトに含めた状態のソースなので、この質問はあまり良くありませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

改めて、Visual Studioでプロジェクトを新規作成するところからやってみました（WCF サービス アプリケーション）。
するとAccount/Login 等は生成されず、意図しないところにRedirectされてしまうという問題は発生しなくなりました。